# Get info from a mac game in fullscreen in python

Tags: python, macos, fullscreen

I am creating a python script to automate mac games. To do this I am using the Accessibility API, so I can get the AXApplication element and then I can get its AXWindows, AXChildren, attributes, actions, etc.

This works fine while the game is in window mode. But, when I change it to full screen, then the AXWindows list is empty and is like if the application has not windows anymore. So, I cannot get the game window size, location, etc.

Is it any way (using the accessibility API or another different API) to get the game window while it is in full screen mode in order to get the attributes and actions and to manipulate the game from it?